# Tough problem on markov chain transition matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, markov-chains

Let a Markov chain with state space$\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ have stationary transition probability matrix $$P=\begin{pmatrix}.1&0&.2&.7&0\\0&1&0&0&0\\.7&0&.1&.2&0\\.2&0&.7&.1&0\\0&.5&0&0&.5\end{pmatrix}$$ 
Then, which of the following are right?:$$a)\sum_{i=1}^5\lim_{n\to\infty}P_{ij}^n=1$$
   $$b)\lim_{n\to\infty}P_{ij}^n=\frac1{3}$$
$$c)\sum_{n=1}^\infty P_{33}^n\lt \infty$$
As for $c)$, I used the pr operty that $3$ is a recurrent state, hence the desired sum should be divergent. But, what about the other two parts? Eigenvalue decomposition seems lengthy. Any ideas. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: It might be worth checking the original matrix for reducibility and absorbing states

Comment: @Henry yes, I think the chain has $3$ classes:$\{1,3,4\},\{2\}$ and $\{5\}$ and the state $\{2\}$ is an absorbing one. Am i right?

Comment: Indeed.  And from the transition probabilities among the $\{1,3,4\}$ especially their symmetry I would guess $$\lim_{n\to\infty}P^n=\begin{pmatrix}\frac13&0&\frac13&\frac13&0\\0&1&0&0&0\\\frac13&0&\frac13&\frac13&0\\\frac13&0&\frac13&\frac13&0\\0&1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @Henry how did you get that, I mean the values on the matrix? Did you just use the fact that the probability that jumping from anyone of the states $1,3,4$ in their class is equally likely?

Comment: Comparing $(.1,.2,.7)$ with $(.7,.1,.2)$ and $(.2,.7,.1)$

Comment: @Henry yes, so that means that jumping from anyone of those states is equally likely, right?

Comment: it means any stable distribution is uniform among these three states

Comment: Even if you don’t use @Henry’s shortcut, you don’t need to do a full eigendecomposition to see what the steady state distributions are. They are the left eigenvectors of $1$, so you just have to compute the kernel of $P^T-I$ and normalize so that you get probability vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $P_{22} = 1$, and state 5 leads to 2 or 5 only, meaning 5 is a transitive state. 1, 3 and 4 are in their own recurrence class with a double stochastic matrix, i.e. a limiting distribution is uniform in this class.

Back to the question, since state 5 is transitive, $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P_{5j}^n = 0$ (except may be for $j=2$)- you just leave the state eventually. [so b) can't be right]

and eventually, also $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P_{i5}^n=0$.